# Why does RecyclerView scroll to top of view when view is focused

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, keyboard

I have `RecyclerView`, some kind of chat. Items are `TextViews` The layout is reversed. Input field below `RecyclerView`. When I scroll to the bottom of `RecyclerView` and click to the bottom item it gets focused (only when it gets focused, not every click) and `RecyclerView` scrolls automatically to the top of that item (when the text in item is larger than screen height).

Also when the keyboard is visible and I click to `RecyclerView` item - keyboard hides and recycler view scrolls to the top of that item, how to disable such behavior?

I want it to stay at the same position when it was when the keyboard was opened or where it was when I clicked on some item.

Keyboard is hiding with this method

```
* * * * 
inputView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (!hasFocus){
            hideKeyboard();
        } 
    });
* * * * 

public void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)

    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

And `RecyclerView` configured in such way:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageList);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter = new chatAdapter(getContext()));
```

If I make a button and will call `hideKeyBoard()` by clicking that button - its ok, it does not scroll, but when I click on RecyclerView item - it gets focused and scroll to top of that item

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, I extended LinearLayoutManager and override some methods. Now it not scrolling to focused items. Maybe someone knows better solution?

```
public class NotScrollingToFocuesChildrenLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
public NotScrollingToFocuesChildrenLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NotScrollingToFocuesChildrenLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public NotScrollingToFocuesChildrenLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public boolean onRequestChildFocus(RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state, View child, View focused) {
    //return super.onRequestChildFocus(parent, state, child, focused);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onRequestChildFocus(RecyclerView parent, View child, View focused) {
    //return super.onRequestChildFocus(parent, child, focused);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be your solution as well: [RecyclerView scrolls to top after keyboard hides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461261/recyclerview-scrolls-to-top-after-keyboard-hides?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

[Android Developer Site link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> "adjustResize"
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard on screen.
>
> "adjustPan"
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.