# RecyclerView scrolls to top after keyboard hides

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` with height and width `matchParent`, above and below some views. View below `recyclerView` is `editText`. When something is typed in `editText` and keyboard closes, `recyclerView` scrolls to top. Any idea why it is happening and how it can be resolved.

Related xml at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/42c38f8a50daf0f441552c985e29a309

Comment: Can u add your xml code

Comment: I home this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458054/why-does-recyclerview-scroll-to-top-of-view-when-view-is-focused
I think it is the same problem.

Comment: Use Custom linear layout manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this code to your manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/title_activity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
    >
```

EDIT

Comment: @seema you can try             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"